# can cocos creator use native c library?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocoscreator

I know Android lets dev to use `.so` for native code. Is there a way to do the same in cocos creator? The native library has c and c++. I have access to them so building them to a different format that cocos creator use will not be an issue, but that's all I can do with those native code. I can't copy/share which means I can only build those native code to certain format that can be used in cocos creator, and the output lib has to be of course binary code.